# Replace largo if, else if... else with FOR or something more compact

Tags: if-statement

I receive via POST a value. Then, I´m comparing the value received (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) with variables pre defined in my code.
Is it possible to do it with FOR or another way to simplify it without changing the functionality of the code?
Yes, I need to receive the value as number and compare it with variables (no MYSQL).

I set on each test the name, eg: $varname = "Paul";

Here´s what I´m doing and what I´d like to change.
Thanks a lot

```
// from previous page with input name thenumber
$thenumber = $_POST['thenumber'];

$option1 = "1";
$option1 = "2";
$option1 = "3";
$option1 = "4";
$option1 = "5";
$option1 = "6";
...
...
More options

if($thename == $option1)
{
$varname = "Paul";
}
else if ($thename == $option2)
{
$varname = "Louie";
}
else if ($thename == $option3)
{
$varname = "Dimitri";
}
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much cleaner to do this with a `switch`.
I don't think using a `for` loop will be a good idea.

Be sure to put a `break` after each case ends.
The `default` case is when `$thename` is none of the numbers in the cases.

```
switch ($thename) {
    case 1:
        $varname = "paul";
        break;
    case 2:
        $varname = "Louie";
        break;
    case 3:
        $varname = "Dimitri";
        break;
    ...
    default:
        $varname = "default_name";
        break;
}
```

Comment: That´s WHAT I was looking for... Switch... God! Thanks a lot!